# Graph API me/friends/ always return empty

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i used to create Facebook APP, checked to get friends list using Access token from Graph API Explorer, it always returning empty data

Comment: Duplicated, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**Facebook was updated with version 2.0,**

if you want to use Graph API me/friends/, you need to submit your app for review.

Steps to do it:

goto your Apps -->  status and Review ---> start a Submission.

then you need to provide your information for review with screen shot.

**Submit Items for Approval**

```
Some Facebook integrations require approval before public usage.
Before submitting your app for review, please consult our Platform Policy and Review Guidelines.
```

Comment: why is this set as correct answer? you don´t need to submit your app for review for /me/friends. user_friends is one of the permissions you do NOT need to get reviewed. check out my answer, everything you need to know is in there.

Answer (score 14):

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/

Check those Links, Facebook made a big step forward towards privacy. `/me/friends` only returns friends who authorized the App too, that´s why the result is empty.

Comment: For me it returns empty but a friend of mine also authorized the app. Is it norma?

Comment: did both users authorize with user_friends?

Answer (score 3):

With the introduction of the Facebook Graph API 2.0, access a user’s friends list was removed and limited to just friends who use the same application. However, Facebook added two new APIs to allow retrieval of Friend names (and indirectly a friend count). The two new APIs are taggable_friends and invitable_friends.

Comment: This sounds good, except that if the user has special privacy settings, the list will still be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

In v2.0 of the Graph API, calling /me/friends returns the person's friends who also use the app.

Check this link: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

When I login with ID my friend and retry send request "me/friends" again. It return ID my Facebook to me. If you need test, you can use this way.

Answer (score -2):

I have currently find this one useful, just posting a snippet:

```
  FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
      message: 'Please sign up .',
      filters: ['app_non_users']
    }, function(response){
        console.log("Response from app requests:"+response);
    });
```

Reference url https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.1#params